# HTML not escaped in titles of questions for "deleted" events in profile "reputation" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, security

This is working correctly in some instances, but not others

[image]

```
<tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
        <td class="rep-left">
                <span class="rep-up">+1</span>
        </td>

        <td class="rep-time" title="2012-03-03 19:07:11Z">
            7 mins ago
        </td>
                <td class="rep-desc" title="post was deleted">deleted</td>
            <td class="rep-link">Why is my <select> value not being posted in email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">

        <td class="rep-left">
            <span class="rep-down">-1</span>
        </td>
        <td class="rep-time" title="2012-03-03 19:06:00Z">
            8 mins ago
        </td>
                <td class="rep-desc" title="downvoted a post">downvoted</td>
            <td class="rep-link"><a href="/questions/9548873/why-is-my-select-value-not-being-posted-in-email/9548980#9548980" class="answer-hyperlink ">Why is my &lt;select&gt; value not being posted in email</a></td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: Oh looks like Nick forgot to run the new events through the sanitizer. It works for the "downvoted" event because that one existed before. The "deleted" event was just added. :)

Comment: [Ha ha ha](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQ1j.png).

Comment: (10ks/mods will see a link, other users will get an `alert()`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

Beatings are being doled out to those responsible.

Comment: Nothing like a good Saturday beating. Do I mark this as answered? First time on meta...

Comment: @nachito Most users would.